# Using QueryOver how do I write a Where statement against an "is in"

Tags: c#, nhibernate, where-clause, queryover

When using QueryOver, I normally write a Where clause where the field exactly matches a value:

```
var subset = _session.QueryOver<ProviderOrganisation>()
.Where(x => x.Type == "Hospital")
.List<ProviderOrganisation>();
```

But now I want to match the field against a list of values, so in SQL something like a "Where x is in ():"

```
var subset = _session.QueryOver<ProviderOrganisation>()
.Where(x => x.Code is In (ListOfSubsetCodes))
.List<ProviderOrganisation>();
```

How do I do that please?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use contains to do a in:

```
.Where(x => ListOfSubsetCodes.Contains (x.Code))
```

Answer (score 4):

You've used QueryOver, and another way of doing this:

```
.WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.Code).IsIn(ListOfSubsetCodes)
```

I think `x => ListOfSubsetCodes.Contains()` will work well for LINQ, but not for QueryOver.

Comment: That's really helpful Anton - I'd never seen that before. Thanks